# Without Canvas(HTML5 element), how to measure TextMetrics like ascent, descent, CapHeight of font in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, fonts, html5-canvas, fontmetrics

**Note:**

1. I need ascent descent and CapHeight of font and not just line-height.
2. Need metrics using client-side Scripting(JavaScipt).

Comment: Hi, what have you tried so far and what has your research shown you? Can you say why canvas is not allowed? There's not that much else you can use other than offsetHeight perhaps with different scenarios. Is JS all you can use? And what font type/format, would it not be better to look at the actual typeface design info?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [opentype.js](https://opentype.js.org/font-inspector.html) to parse a font to get values in the font's [OS/2 table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/typography/opentype/spec/os2). For ascent, descent and cap height, use the sTypoAscender, sTypoDescender and sCapHeight fields.